# Number of prime implicants

Tags: digital-logic

How many  prime Implicants are there, 2 or 3? 
F(w,x,y,z)=Σ(5,7,8,10)+d(9,11,13,15)
[image]

I am confused if red block will be counted as Prime Impicant or not?

Comment: Is it just me or have there been so many questions about Prime Implicants recently?

Comment: It's not just you. There have even been several that were clearly from the same homework assignment. I wonder if Stack Exchange is especially popular at some particular university.

Comment: I don't know about others.. I am currently studying this topic for a competitive examination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicant#Prime_implicant):

> A prime implicant of a function is an implicant that cannot be covered
>   by a more general, (more reduced - meaning with fewer literals)
>   implicant.

it is a prime implicant as it cannot be covered by some other (single) implicant.

But it is not an **essential** prime implicant [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicant#Prime_implicant):

> Essential prime implicants (aka core prime implicants) are prime
>   implicants that cover an output of the function that no combination of
>   other prime implicants is able to cover.

because it is fully covered by two other implicants.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's fulfilling the conditions for prime implicants but is there any rule for incompletely specified functions that a block MUST include atleast 1 minterm from the function otherwise it won't be considered as prime implicant ?

Comment: No. These terms have no notion of incomplete function. Once you choose specific "don't cares" to be your `1`s , you have completely defined your function.

Comment: I have never seen a formal definition stating that. Don't cares is just a transparent way to let you choose one of the several possible functions fulfilling your requirements.

Comment: Even I think it's a valid prime implicant. Thank you